# How to add @Published property wrapper to class member in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do something like this where I can publish changes to an array on a class, but when I add the `@Published` property wrapper to `items` in `Group` I get this error on my Group class.

```
class Item: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text = "Hello World!"
}

class Group: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    // Type 'Group' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
    // Type 'Group' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
}

var group = Group()
```

Comment: No it does not. I also need to encode my published property.

Comment: The comment in the linked topic mentions "The error is basically telling you that the type Published<Data?> does not conform to Decodable.". Did you try to follow his advice? If it still doesn't work, what is the error this time? I also saw this [topic](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127345) from apple forum, but I don't use swift so not sure if it's helpful.